# Python singleton again / how to use class attributes?

Tags: python

I would like to have a singleton class in Python with Java like "static class attributes". I read the several posts existing on Python singletons and can not find a solution except using a simple module as singleton.

Is there a way to extends this code ([PEP318](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/)) to use it with "static class attributes" that I can access from the functions?

```
def singleton(cls):
    instances = {}
    def getinstance():
        if cls not in instances:
            instances[cls] = cls()
        return instances[cls]
    return getinstance

@singleton
class MyClass:
    ...
```

Comment: [Singleton? We don't need no stinkin' singleton: the Borg design pattern (Python recipe)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531/) :)

Comment: Re @Paulo's comment, make sure you read the comments about new style classes on that page.

Comment: There are loads of ways to simulate this effect in a single module - trivially, just create a class and then have a factory that always returns the same instance of it (or just make the instance part of the module's namespace). We're all consenting adults here - no need to keep things secret.

Comment: I'm going to go further than my last comment. Almost all the really nasty bugs I've had to work through in Python were when I did nefarious mangling behind the scenes in an attempt to create the "perfect" interface. The Borg design pattern smells heavily of nefarious mangling (as does any idea of a protected singleton). Just tell your users what's going on, and let them stick their fingers in the sockets if they want to.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I already read about the new style classes. I think Aya brings it to the point with the @classmethod annotation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TBH, I've always found the singleton to be an anti-pattern.

If you want an object which will only ever have a single instance, then why bother even instantiating anything? Just do something like...

```
class MyCounter(object):
    count = 0

    @classmethod
    def inc(cls, delta=1):
        cls.count += delta

>>> MyCounter.count
0
>>> MyCounter.inc()
>>> MyCounter.count
1
>>> MyCounter.inc(5)
>>> MyCounter.count
6
```

Comment: Thanks! The decorator was what I have been looking for.